# Cucumber BDD Automation scripts will always result to "Skipped" tests after running

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, junit, cucumber, bdd

I'm trying to create a BDD test framework using Cucumber-Maven-Selenium.

Originally the script don't have "Super Class" and "test setup"
and runs smoothly without errors.
But when I added the "super class" and "test setup",
running the script will always result to skipping all tests.

Can someone help me what's wrong with this?

Please see below for the scripts.

**Feature file**

```
Feature: Login Feature
  Verify if user is able to Login in to the site

  Scenario: Login as a authenticated user
    Given user is on homepage
    When user navigates to Login Page
    And user enters username and Password
    Then success message is displayed
```

**Super Class**

```
package seleniumgluecode;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class driverInstance {
    protected static WebDriver driver;
    
    protected WebDriver getDriver() {
        if(driver == null) {
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        }
        return driver;
    }
}
```

**Steps implementation**

```
package seleniumgluecode;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;

public class test extends driverInstance {
    
    WebDriver driver = getDriver();
    runSettings objRun = new runSettings();
    
    @Given("^user is on homepage$")
    public void user_is_on_homepage() throws Throwable {
        objRun.runSetup();
        driver.get("http://automationpractice.com/index.php");
    }
    
    @When("^user navigates to Login Page$")
    public void user_navigates_to_Login_Page() throws Throwable {
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sign in")).click();
    }
    
    @When("^user enters username and Password$")
    public void user_enters_username_and_Password() throws Throwable {
        driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("blog.cucumber@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("passwd")).sendKeys("Cucumber@blog");
        driver.findElement(By.id("SubmitLogin")).click();   
    }
    
    @Then("^success message is displayed$")
    public void success_message_is_displayed() throws Throwable {
        String exp_message = "Welcome to your account. Here you can manage all of your personal information and orders.";
        String actual = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".info-account")).getText();
        Assert.assertEquals(exp_message, actual); 
        objRun.runTearDown();
    }    
}
```

**runner**

```
package seleniumgluecode;

import java.io.File;

import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

//import com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter;
import com.cucumber.listener.Reporter;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features ="src/test/java/features/test.feature",
        glue= "src/test/java/seleniumgluecode",
        plugin = { "com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:target/cucumber-reports/report.html"}, 
        monochrome = true
                )

public class runner {
    @AfterClass
    public static void writeExtentReport() {
        Reporter.loadXMLConfig(new File("config/report.xml"));
    
    }
}
```

**test setup**

```
package seleniumgluecode;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class runSettings extends driverInstance {
    WebDriver driver = getDriver();
    
    public void runSetup() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","R:/Installers/Automation/chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
    
    public void runTearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<groupId>Cucumber_Selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>Cucumber_Selenium</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>Cucumber_Selenium</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
  
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/cobertura/cobertura -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cobertura</groupId>
        <artifactId>cobertura</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-jvm-deps -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.masterthought/cucumber-reporting -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/gherkin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-all -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.19</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.vimalselvam/cucumber-extentsreport -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aventstack/extentreports -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```